# How to enable smooth zooming in Bokeh?

Tags: bokeh, mpld3

I have just starting looking into making my python graphs interactive. Bokeh seems to have a lot of functionality and I am currently trying it out. One thing that I find aesthetically pleasing with the mpld3 library is the smooth zooming after selecting a region with the zoom tool ([like in this example](http://mpld3.github.io/examples/html_tooltips.html)). The default behavior in Bokeh seems to be to jump to the zoomed region without  without any animation ([example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/iris.html), 'wheel zoom' is smooth, but 'box zoom' is not).

Is the smooth zooming feature available in Bokeh and just disabled by default, or is this not implemented?

Answer (score 1):

This is not implemented as of Bokeh 0.8.2, we do plan to add support for animation, key frames, etc. and smooth box zoom would probably best be implemented on top of that.